# Twilio - unable to get and delete private channels

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I have create some private channels.During chat,I left the channel after chat finished.But now I am not able to get and delete those  private channels.

`getSubscribedChannels` not returning the list of those private channels.

Also,If I do login in Twilio account,**`DELETE`** button also not appearing when I select any channel either private or public.

Comment: What is the code you are using to try to delete the channels and how is it not working. Which SDK is this using (JS, iOS, Android) or is it the REST API?

Comment: @philnash I am using JS(Node/jQuery) to build chat.

Comment: Ok, that's a start, but what's the context around this particular issue? Perhaps you could edit your question and share some of the relevant code and let me know what errors you are facing.

Comment: Same issue, @RIYAJKHAN did you get solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved using the REST API Delete Channel (https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/rest/channels?code-sample=code-delete-a-channel&code-language=js&code-sdk-version=3.x).

With the REST API you can authenticate with an auth token provided by Twilio and delete the channel.